# How can I remove a saved/configured WiFi network from my Android device using WifiManager?

Tags: android, wifi, hotspot

Way to delete Saved/Configured WiFi networks programmatically

I added a network suggestion by the below lines of code and added the same under saved/configured networks.

```
 val passpointSuggestion = WifiNetworkSuggestion.Builder()
                    .setPasspointConfig(config)
                    .setIsHiddenSsid(false)
                    .setIsAppInteractionRequired(true)
                    .build()

 val networkSuggestionList = listOf(passpointSuggestion)
 wifiManager.removeNetworkSuggestions(networkSuggestionList)
 suggestionsList.add(passpointSuggestion)
```

I can see my added network suggestion under saved/configured networks, also I can fetch the same with the below lines of code:

```
 val suggestionResults = wifiManager.networkSuggestions
```

Now I want to remove the added saved/configured wifi from the WiFi listof thee  device,
I tried with:

```
val configuationResults = wifiManager.configuredNetworks
```

which always returns null on `Android 11,12 and 13`

Any suggestions are most appreciated.

Comment: Hello, did u find any solution to this ?